# Information about number of simplex and barrier iterations in OPL CPLEX

Tags: cplex, opl

I would like to know how can I obtain the exact number of simplex and barrier iterations used by CPLEX in OPL. The solution reports the total number of iterations but I want them to be separated (Barrier and Simplex).

Comment: Would you elaborate more on what you are looking for? It seems the Barrier and crossover iterations could be seen separately somewhere in the engine tab and its log file. Do you want anything more?